# How Queue with Linked List Works

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, queue

Could someone please explain me how the `enqueue` method works?

- I am wondering how the front gets updated when rear is re-assigned?

  ```
   public class Queue { 
   public QNode front, rear; 

   public Queue() 
   { 
       this.front = null;
       this.rear = null; 
   } 

   public void enqueue(int key) 
   {
       QNode temp = new QNode(key); 

       if (this.rear == null) { 
           this.rear = temp;
           this.front = temp; 
           return; 
       }

       this.rear.next = temp; 

       this.rear = temp;
   } 


   public void dequeue() 
   { 
       if (this.front == null) 
           return; 

       QNode temp = this.front; 
       this.front = this.front.next; 

       if (this.front == null) 
           this.rear = null; 
   }
  ```

  }

Comment: “How [does] the front gets updated when rear is re-assigned?” — It doesn’t (for a non-empty list transition). This is because each node knows the previous and next nodes. Front simply refers to the first node (which knows about the second which..). In the double-linked approach, as shown here, this creates a chain of nodes that can be traversed in each direction. Remembering the rear node reduces the complexity of operations that start from the tail such as appending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the method creates a new node with the given key, then it checks if the rear is empty (which actually means that the queue is empty). If the queue is empty, it sets the new node with the key as the rear and the front since it's the only node in the list. If the list isn't empty, it links the node to the rear (`this.rear.next==temp`) and updates it as the new rear.

As for your question about the front, it doesn't need to be updated when you use enqueue. Enqueue adds a node to the end of the list and updates it as the rear. Dequeue removes a node from the front and updates the new front (the one after the original front).

Comment: Hi @Ethan, thank you for the clarification. Just a follow up question, 
- when (this.rear = temp;) is called, the rear is updated yeah, but then (this.rear.next) is null. Which means previous assignment to rear.next is discarded?

Comment: First, let me just clarify that if the method enters the "if" block it ends at the end of it (there's a return command).
In the case it didn't enter the "if" block, it means there are already nodes in the queue.(not empty)
Then, "this.rear.next=temp" sets the new node as the node that comes after the current rear, and "this.rear=temp" sets the new node as the new rear.